# C# Linq select object in List where int in object child List<int> occurs n times

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `List<TestObj> ListOfTestObjs` of type

```
public class TestObj
{
    public List<int> Ints;
}
```

How do i perform a Linq query that returns an object in the list if the case is that a given integer x occurs n times, and returns null if not? Something like this:

```
ListOfTestObjs.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Ints == x occurs 3 times in Ints)
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If `x` is the number you are looking for and `n` is the number of times it should occur in the inner collection:

```
ListOfTestObjs.FirstOrDefault(l => l.Ints.Count(i => i == x) == n);
```